# Organization Browser of any user (not just current user)

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ad, organization-browser

I want to get organization browser for any user not just current user that is logged in. How can I make it happen? any advise? : )

*note: I cannot use visual studio.*

Comment: By organization browser do you mean Organization chart ?

if yes then you can use GetOrgChart.js or any similar javascript to create one of your own

Comment: by organization browser I mean organization browser web part in sharepoint 2013. I didn't understand you well about GetOrgChart part, please be more specific.

Comment: Try [this](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/create-organizational-chart-sharepoint-office-2013) link for creating org charts.

Comment: I already read this topic before posting question. I cannot export and then import user list to excel. it must be done in sharepoint only.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following in a script editor below your Org Browser Webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function CreateHierarchyChartControl(parentId, profileId, type, persistControlId, flowDirection, silverLightControlId)
{
    profileId = "WINDOWS\\username"; //added line

    var initParam = profileId + ',' + type + ',' + persistControlId + ',' + flowDirection + ',' + silverLightControlId;
    var host = document.getElementById(parentId);

    host.setAttribute('width', '100%');
    host.setAttribute('height', '100%');

    Silverlight.createObject('/_layouts/ClientBin/hierarchychart.xap',
        host,
        silverLightControlId,
        {
            top: '30',
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            version: '4.0.50401.0',
            isWindowless: 'true',
            enableHtmlAccess: 'true'
        },
        {
            onLoad: OnHierarchyChartLoaded
        },
        initParam,
        null);
}

</script> ​​
```